# Google sheets conditional formatting range of dates

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight cells based on a range of dates so that one can visually see from what month to what month one unit plan takes.

Please see this page (row 9) as a reference: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VDE1IdRJ7EB59NDos_A7DEUBm5LA75akbqiRVoH5IkI/edit#gid=222884255&range=G9

For example, if a unit goes from 4/2023 to 6/2023, I'd like April, May, and June boxes to be highlighted. I used the "custom formula" option in conditional formatting and input this formula:

=AND(($G$9:$R$9>=$E9),($G$9:$R$9<=$F9))

However, nothing is lighting up for me. The dates I'm using come from another Sheet (Grade 7). Could that be an issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Hoping to see highlighted cells but the colors are not showing up.

I tried this formula: =AND(($G$9:$R$9>=$E9),($G$9:$R$9<=$F9))

Answer (score 0):

Your sheet is not public, from what I guess, you may try with next formula for the whole range. It will automatically expand G to R:

```
=AND((G$9>=$E9),(G$9<=$F9))
```

Comment: Apologies. I fixed the share settings. I tried the suggested formula but no luck.